# iPhone - View/Close Button Localization on remote Push Notification Dialog

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone know how to do the localization for the default button "View/Close" on push notification alert dialog?

Just like the following images:
http://img267.imageshack.us/i/img0014b.png/ (Swedish)
http://img696.imageshack.us/i/img0015i.png/ (English)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to **Localized Formatted Strings** section in [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

Comment: Yes I have read it, but only the right button can be localized...I don't know how to apply it for the left button.

Comment: I don't think that you need to localize the Close button. Its localization will depend on the device's current locale.

Comment: That's what exactly I'm thinking. I have set my device to Traditional Chinese and HK region. However, the dialog close/view buttons are still display in English :(

Comment: Ok it seems it is a bug for iOS 5.0. I have found another device using iOS4.3 and the push notification alert buttons localization will depend on device's current locale.